# Выйти через выход (войти через вход)

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация

На странице выхода из сети *StackExchange* говорится о нажатии кнопки "Выход", однако сама кнопка называется "Выйти":

> [image: выйти через выход]

В меню пункт также называется "выйти" (но с маленькой буквы):

> [image: выйти меню]

Для полноты картины для входа везде используется вариант "вход" (с учетом нужного регистра в месте использования):

> [image: вход]

Нужно привести в соответствие.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, потыркашись пару минут, кнопку я так и не нашел, да и пункт меню изрядно упрятан. Может вытащить это действие (выход) куда-то наверх? Например, в верхний правый угол страницы, рядом с полем поиска.

Comment: @avp вытаскивать - это менять структуру **всех** сайтов. На такое не пойдут. А вот поменять перевод мы в состоянии самостоятельно.

Comment: @alexolut, так исправление планируется? Update: ой, не тот вопрос. Нужен тот, что с очередями проверок.

Comment: @Qwertiy планируется. Только пока нет явного фаворита в ответах.

Answer (score 3):

Для выхода оставить везде только вариант "Выход" (с учетом регистра). Вход не трогать.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать пары "Выйти"/"Войти" (с учетом регистра) для соответствующих пунктов.

Comment: Мой голос прошу учесть для этого варианта.

Comment: Если мы для действий используем глаголы, тогда уж и «отменить» вместо «отмена»?

Comment: @VladD в оригинале там "cancel", "Log Out", "Log in". Для "cancel" вроде как уже сложился устоявшийся перевод в IT как "отмена". А остальные суть есть глаголы: "Выйти" и "Войти".

Comment: Ну, по идее не обязательно ориентироваться на английский текст, главное передать смысл. Так что это, возможно, отдельный вопрос. Я бы всё же сделал если глаголы, то везде.

Answer (score 0):

Для выхода оставить везде только вариант "Выйти" (с учетом регистра). Вход не трогать.